# Binding DataGridView to implementing class in .NET

Tags: c#, data-binding, gridview, interface

How should I bind my collection of T objects which implements an interface and adds more properties to a DataGrid? Here is an example:

```
// interface
public interface IPerson{
[DisplayName(@"FullName")]
string Name{ get; }
}

// implementation
public class Employee : IPerson{
[DisplayName(@"Net Salary")]
public int Salary { 
    get { return 1000; }
}

public string Name{
    get { return "Foo"; }
}

// collection
SortableBindingList<IPerson> MyList { get; set }
...
...
MyList.Add(new Employee());
...
dataGridView.DataSource = MyList;
```

When I do this, it only binds Name but not Salary.

Is there any way to bind to both the properties (Name and Salary in this case)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of `Salary` is not in your `IPerson` interface definition.

You should either add Salary to your `IPerson` interface and implement that in your `Employee` class or change your MyList property definition as below;

```
SortableBindingList<Employee> MyList { get; set }
```

**Edit After Comments**

You can achive your goal by implementing `ITypedList`. It is not a trivial task. So i would not recommend you to do that if you do not have to.

You may inherit from `SortableBindingList<IPerson>` and implement `ITypedList`. You should also create a custom `PropertyDescriptor` to get it work.

Here is a good article about the subject [Virtual Properties](http://jopinblog.wordpress.com/2007/04/30/implementing-itypedlist-for-virtual-properties/) that i have just found. (The article is the first result of searching the ITypedList and PropertyDescriptor keywords together by the time being).

Hope this help.

Comment: Nope. I cannot do this either. Because I've also got another class Student that implements Person. And depending on a setting, I can either create a list of Employee or Student. That's the reason for using an interface rather than anything else.

Comment: Has student class a salary property?

Comment: It looks like you are doing something logically wrong but you can achive your goal by a custom binding solution such as implementing ITypedList or IBindingList. I suggest you to check the requirements and your solution again rather than going to the custom binding way.

Comment: I'm looking into ITypedList but even with that I cannot get it right. I belive that ITypedList is the way to do it but no luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is in your interface, but `Salary` isn't.  Add `Salary` to your interface and it should work fine.

If you don't want to change your interface, use `SortableBindingList<Employee> MyList` instead of `SortableBindingList<IPerson> MyList`

Comment: What if, for some reasons, I'm not allowed to do that?

Comment: Yes, I can change the datasource definition. I've the source code (it is just a pet project that I'm working on). The only restriction is that I cannot add Salary property to the base interface.

Answer (score -1):

You can force the DataGridView to look at the actual objects instead of the interface by casting to object. In my example I use VB.NET but it is probably not hard for you to translate to C#.

```
dataGridView.DataSource = New SortableBindingList(Of Object)(MyList.Cast(Of Object).ToList())
```

In my case MyList is an `IList(Of IPerson)`.